# DKMS Modules Installation Error - Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS

Tags: kernel, apt, dpkg, acpi, dkms

I am getting the following error everytime I do **$sudo apt upgrade**

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 
mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up system76-acpi-dkms (1.0.2~1678132042~22.04~ed01124) ...
Removing old system76_acpi-1.0.2~1678132042~22.04~ed01124 DKMS files...
Deleting module system76_acpi-1.0.2~1678132042~22.04~ed01124 completely from the DKMS 
tree.
Loading new system76_acpi-1.0.2~1678132042~22.04~ed01124 DKMS files...
Building for 6.2.0-76060200-generic
Building initial module for 6.2.0-76060200-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.2.0-76060200-generic is not 
supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-76060200-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/system76_acpi/1.0.2~1678132042~22.04~ed01124/build/make.log for 
more information.
dpkg: error processing package system76-acpi-dkms (--configure):
installed system76-acpi-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-76060200-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/ip_discovery.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega10_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_cap.bin for module 
amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_11_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_11_toc.bin for module 
amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_10_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_10_sos.bin for module 
amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_imu.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_imu.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_toc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sdma_6_0_3.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes1.bin for module 
amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module 
amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_mes1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_mes1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/smu_13_0_10.bin for module amdgpu
kernelstub.Config    : INFO     Looking for configuration...
kernelstub           : INFO     System information: 

OS:..................Pop!_OS 22.04
Root partition:....../dev/nvme0n1p7
Root FS UUID:........d5eabcf1-da1f-441e-9eb7-67bd5243d327
ESP Path:............/boot/efi
ESP Partition:......./dev/nvme0n1p6
ESP Partition #:.....6
NVRAM entry #:.......-1
Boot Variable #:.....0000
Kernel Boot Options:.quiet loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=false splash
Kernel Image Path:.../boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-76060200-generic
Initrd Image Path:.../boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-76060200-generic
Force-overwrite:.....False

kernelstub.Installer : INFO     Copying Kernel into ESP   
kernelstub.Installer : INFO     Copying initrd.img into ESP
kernelstub.Installer : INFO     Setting up loader.conf configuration
kernelstub.Installer : INFO     Making entry file for Pop!_OS
kernelstub.Installer : INFO     Backing up old kernel
kernelstub.Installer : INFO     Making entry file for Pop!_OS
Errors were encountered while processing:
 system76-acpi-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And the status of my dkms is as follows **$sudo dkms status**

```
system76/1.0.14~1643391291~22.04~78ede46, 5.17.15-76051715-generic, x86_64: installed
system76/1.0.14~1643391291~22.04~78ede46, 6.1.11-76060111-generic, x86_64: installed
system76_acpi/1.0.2~1678132042~22.04~ed01124: added
system76-io/1.0.2~1655490480~22.04~0217576, 5.17.15-76051715-generic, x86_64: 
installed
system76-io/1.0.2~1655490480~22.04~0217576, 6.1.11-76060111-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: The log `/var/lib/dkms/system76_acpi/1.0.2~1678132042~22.04~ed01124/build/make.log` may contain more information about why the module failed to build.

Comment: Possibly relevant comment from closed Ask Ubuntu posting: _"If you read your messages, it clearly shows non-Ubuntu 3rd party (system76) packages, a testing grade kernel (supported kernels on 22.04 are 5.15 (GA), 5.19 (HWE) and -edge will be 6.1 but currently not yet available for jammy users by default as not far enough yet in testing; Ubuntu prizes stability don't forget across loads of makes/devices; where System76 tests only for devices they sell). Packages Pop OS use are available for Ubuntu for testing if users wish, but not by default until deemed stable."_

Comment: I have the same issue. Additionally my docking station is not working properly, so I can only use the internal display of my laptop. It's working when I choose an older kernel (hold spacebar when booting).

Comment: Thanks, I guess the first thing I should have done is check the logs. The problem was, gcc-12 was not installed. It fixed it all. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue and I managed to solve it by installing gcc-12:

```
sudo apt install gcc-12
```

After dkms config ran without errors. However, I still can't use my external monitor with this kernel version. There seems to be a bug affecting external monitors / docking stations...

Comment: Thank you a lot! This solution helped. Everything is working fine, though I don't have an external monitor so I can't say anything about it.